# Passing a parameter from HTML to TS, computing, displaying the result back in TS

Tags: angular

The model in the backend has a category (id, name), and questions (id, name, category Category) etc.

The 2 big issues are `create` and `display`.

While displaying question info, I am trying to get the category which was set when I created the question in the back end, get the category name, and show that category name with the rest of the question fields.

It works, except for the category - getCategName - where I am getting
[object Object].
Does anyone see where it's going wrong?

component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <td class="hidden">{{question.id}}</td>
    <td>{{question.name}}</td>
    <td>{{question.difficulty}}</td>
    <td>{{getCategName(question.id)}}</td> ???????????
    <td>{{question.content}}</td>
```

component.ts

```
export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit {
    questions: Question[];
    ngOnInit() {
        this.questionService.getQuestions()
        .subscribe( data => {
            this.questions = data;
        });
        getCategName(id: string) {
            return this.questionService.getQuestCatNameById(id); 
        };
    }
```

service.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
)
export class QuestionService {
    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}
    private questionUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/questions';
    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    public getQuestions() {
        return this.http.get<Question[]>(this.questionUrl);
    }
    public getQuestCatNameById(id){
        return this.http.get<string>(this.baseUrl + 'questCatName/' + id);
    }
```

back end controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/questCatName/{id}")
public String getQuestCatNameById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return repo.findById(Long.valueOf(id)).get().getCategory().getName();
```

Comment: You're not subscribing to the HTTP call returned by `getQuestCatNameById()`.

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(this.questionService.getQuestCatNameById(id))` to see what your service method is outputting? If so, what does that Object look like?

Comment: I'd also recommend you look into a more reactive approach using Observables. You can use the `async` pipe in your template to display data emitted by an Observable (like an HTTP call) and you can `pipe` in your second call to have it all run together. Worth a look :-)

Comment: Will, correct, thank you.
return this.questionService.getQuestCatNameById(id) should have ..subscribe(data => {this.cat = data});

@AndrewHill
It's strange with the console log, since I keep getting an HttpError linked to getQuestCatNameById(8) , 9 etc, which are the question Ids.
hibernate keeps generating queries and needs to be stopped, and the brower restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing: get all the categories separately in an Array.
Suppose allCategories = this.questionService.getAllQuestCatName();

then Do the following on front-end (HTML):

```
  <tr *ngFor="let question of questions">
  <td class="hidden">{{question.id}}</td>
  <td>{{question.name}}</td>
  <td>{{question.difficulty}}</td>
  <td>{{allCategories[question.id]}}</td> ???????????
  <td>{{question.content}}</td>
```

Comment: thanks for the info, but in this case the array with all categories is just:
0: {id: 5, name: "Java", parent: null, children: Array(0)}
1: {id: 6, name: "SQL", parent: null, children: Array(0)}

The questions have IDs of 7, 6, 8 etc and allCategories[question.id]  fails.

Answer (score 0):

There was no need for a service to bring the category name:Category objects come with the question objects, and getQuestCatNameById(id) has no purpose.

All that was needed is {{question.category.name}} in the component.HTML.

Thanks to everyone.